# sql HR schema making a line appear once

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling with this for some time now but I thought I best use the HR schema to show this example:

the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
  department,
  SUM(salary) "Money",
  CASE
    WHEN job_id = 'SA_MAN' 
    THEN 'Y' 
  END "Indicator" 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    first_name || ' ' || last_name AS "name",
    salary,
    job_id,
    department_id depatment 
  FROM
    employees) 
GROUP BY depatment,
  CASE
    WHEN job_id = 'SA_MAN' 
    THEN 'Y' 
  END 
ORDER BY 1 ;
```

From that sql, I have department 80 appearing twice which has SA_MAN with 'Y' and another with null.

My question is how would I have it appearing just the once but looking at whether SA_MAN is there without it appearing twice.

Answer (score 0):

With a minor modification: Don't group by that `case`. Just make a max over it in select clause.

```
SELECT department, 
   Sum(salary) "Money", 
   max(CASE 
       WHEN job_id = 'SA_MAN' THEN 'Y' 
       END)     "Indicator" 
FROM   (SELECT first_name 
           || ' ' 
           || last_name  AS "name", 
           salary, 
           job_id, 
           department_id department 
        FROM   employees) 
GROUP  BY department
ORDER  BY 1;
```

**EDIT:** If you want to get another indicator, then

```
max(CASE WHEN condition THEN 'N/A' END)     "Indicator"
```

But if you want multiple indicators, you can't do it in the same column(nobody can't with a simple datatype). A solution would be to add more columns:

```
SELECT department, 
   Sum(salary) "Money", 
   max(CASE WHEN job_id = 'SA_MAN' THEN 'Y' END)     "IndicatorY"
   max(CASE WHEN condition THEN 'N' END)     "IndicatorN"
   max(CASE WHEN anothercondition THEN 'N/A' END)     "IndicatorNA" 
FROM   (SELECT first_name 
           || ' ' 
           || last_name  AS "name", 
           salary, 
           job_id, 
           department_id department 
        FROM   employees) 
GROUP  BY department
ORDER  BY 1;
```

The columns meaning: 'for this department exists an employee with N or Y or NA, respectively'.

Comment: Thank you Florin, that has worked, Got a follow up question though, say if there was other values say in this case it was null and 'Y', in another scenario if there was other values in there like 'NA', 'N' , 'Y', how would you bring back one line against the one you want to test it against. Thanks again

Comment: @abs786123 Hi, added in answer a try.